# bootstrap scrollspy sidenav not working - last item selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a sticky self-highlighting sidenav to work, and am having one heck of a time figuring out what I'm missing.  The content includes the data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidenav" attributes, yet only the last item in the sidenav is highlighted, and none of the sidenav items highlight on scrolling.  I have an example jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8JkE/

(adjust the width of the result pane so the .sidenav floats to the left side)

Following the docs http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

The $('.sidenav') is affix()'ed. The div.sidenav has a ul w/ class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked". There's a content div w/ data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidenav" and yet, on page load, the last item in the navigation is highlighted, and nothing updates on scroll. What am I missing?

html:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2 sidenav-parent">
        <div class="sidenav">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#a">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#b">b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#c">c</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d">d</a></li>
            <li><a href="#e">e</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span10" id="gimmelove" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidenav">
        <h4 id="a">a</h4><p>Trust fund seitan letterpress, keytar raw denim keffiyeh etsy art party before they sold out master cleanse gluten-free squid scenester freegan cosby sweater. Fanny pack portland seitan DIY, art party lo cavore wolf cliche high life echo park Austin. Cred vinyl keffiyeh DIY salvia PBR, banh mi before they sold out farm-to-table VHS viral locavore cosby sweater. Lomo wolf viral, mustache readymade thundercats keffiyeh craft beer marfa ethical. Wolf salvia freegan, sartorial keffiyeh echo park vegan.</p>
        <h4 id="b">b</h4><p>Trust fund seitan letterpress, keytar raw denim keffiyeh etsy art party before they sold out master cleanse gluten-free squid scenester freegan cosby sweater. Fanny pack portland seitan DIY, art party lo cavore wolf cliche high life echo park Austin. Cred vinyl keffiyeh DIY salvia PBR, banh mi before they sold out farm-to-table VHS viral locavore cosby sweater. Lomo wolf viral, mustache readymade thundercats keffiyeh craft beer marfa ethical. Wolf salvia freegan, sartorial keffiyeh echo park vegan.</p>
        <h4 id="c">c</h4><p>Trust fund seitan letterpress, keytar raw denim keffiyeh etsy art party before they sold out master cleanse gluten-free squid scenester freegan cosby sweater. Fanny pack portland seitan DIY, art party lo cavore wolf cliche high life echo park Austin. Cred vinyl keffiyeh DIY salvia PBR, banh mi before they sold out farm-to-table VHS viral locavore cosby sweater. Lomo wolf viral, mustache readymade thundercats keffiyeh craft beer marfa ethical. Wolf salvia freegan, sartorial keffiyeh echo park vegan.</p>
        <h4 id="d">d</h4><p>Trust fund seitan letterpress, keytar raw denim keffiyeh etsy art party before they sold out master cleanse gluten-free squid scenester freegan cosby sweater. Fanny pack portland seitan DIY, art party lo cavore wolf cliche high life echo park Austin. Cred vinyl keffiyeh DIY salvia PBR, banh mi before they sold out farm-to-table VHS viral locavore cosby sweater. Lomo wolf viral, mustache readymade thundercats keffiyeh craft beer marfa ethical. Wolf salvia freegan, sartorial keffiyeh echo park vegan.</p>
        <h4 id="e">e</h4><p>Trust fund seitan letterpress, keytar raw denim keffiyeh etsy art party before they sold out master cleanse gluten-free squid scenester freegan cosby sweater. Fanny pack portland seitan DIY, art party lo cavore wolf cliche high life echo park Austin. Cred vinyl keffiyeh DIY salvia PBR, banh mi before they sold out farm-to-table VHS viral locavore cosby sweater. Lomo wolf viral, mustache readymade thundercats keffiyeh craft beer marfa ethical. Wolf salvia freegan, sartorial keffiyeh echo park vegan.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>​
```

css:

```
body { margin-top: 20px; }
#gimmelove { background-color:#f3f3f3; }
.sidenav .active a { font-weight:600; background-color:#f3f3f3; }
```

​
js:

```
$('.sidenav').affix();
```

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered a similar issues myself. First off, add the data-spy="scroll" and data-target=".sidenav" attributes to the body tag. It does not work properly when added deeper in the DOM such that the nav element is outside of where the attributes were added.

e.g.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidenav" >
```

One other item to note is that when the nav switches to position fixed, it changes the offset from the top for the a, b, c, d sections, so the positions that were calculated before for the sections are no longer accurate.

Here is your example with the attributes added to the body tag: http://jsfiddle.net/b8JkE/50/

Answer (score 3):

You typically add the `data-spy` and `data-target` attributes to the body tag. The source of confusion is the perceived notion that you can add these data attributes to some other element surrounding the content. The truth is you can add these data attributes to "spy" on another element within the page, but this element must have its own nested scrollbar. An element does not fire scroll events unless it has its own scrollbar.   [Here is your updated JSFiddle where I took your div add added a scrollbar.](http://jsfiddle.net/e3TMv/)

As an aside, you can also wire up scrollspy using a JavaScript method rather than using data attributes.

So you have a few options here.

**Option 1**: Add  `data-spy` and `data-target` attributes to the body tag.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidenav">
```

**Option 2**: Spy on a child element within the page, but make sure the element has its own  scrollbar.

```
<div data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidenav" 
 style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
```

**Option 3**: Call the `scrollspy()` method via JavaScript specifying the body/scrollbar element and the target nav.

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.sidenav' });
        });
</script>
```

Here is a demo page: http://www.lawruk.com/blog/60/twitter-bootstrap-fixed-navigation-with-scrollspy-example

Comment: Option 1 worked for me;  And than you for the detailed explanation as to why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue. I worked around it by changing the Javascript to apply the `scrollspy()` method on the first anchor:

```
$('#a').scrollspy();
```

Oh, and like the others said, the `data-spy` and `data-target` attributes should be in the body tag as well.